# Spring MVC - URL Handling Problem

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, dispatcher

I'm trying to setup a Spring MVC project. I posted my configuration files below. 
I'll be really glad if someone helps me.

Thanks in advance,
With regards,
Talha.

**web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
     <display-name>local</display-name>

     <context-param>
      <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
      <param-value>webapp.root</param-value>
     </context-param>
     <context-param>
      <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>
     <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
          /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>

      <listener>
         <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
       </listener>    

     <servlet>
      <servlet-name>webmvc</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/webmvc-servlet.xml
       </param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>webmvc</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

     <session-config> 
      <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> 
     </session-config> 

     <filter>
      <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
                org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
      </filter-class>
      <init-param>
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param> 
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name> 
       <param-value>true</param-value> 
      </init-param> 
     </filter>

     <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>

     <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>jsp/default.jsp</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>login.htm</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>jsp/login.jsp</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list>

     <error-page>
      <error-code>404</error-code>
      <location>/404.jsp</location>
     </error-page>
     <error-page>
      <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
      <location>/error.jsp</location>
     </error-page>

    </web-app>
```

**webmvc-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

  <bean id="localControllerMethodNameResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.InternalPathMethodNameResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="hnd_"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass"> 
   <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
  </property> 
  <property name="prefix"> 
   <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix"> 
   <value>".jsp"</value>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="localController" class="view.LocalVIEW">
  <property name="methodNameResolver">
   <ref local="localControllerMethodNameResolver"/>
  </property>
  <property name="localBUS">
   <ref bean="localBUS"/>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="mappings">
   <props>
    <prop key="/*.htm">localController</prop>
    <prop key="/*.html">localController</prop>
    <prop key="/*.jsp">localController</prop>
    <prop key="/*.ajax">localController</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="localBUS" class="bus.LocalBUS">
 </bean>

</beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

 <bean id="txProxyTemplate" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="transactionManager">
   <ref local="transactionManager" />
  </property>
  <property name="transactionAttributes">
   <props>
    <prop key="list*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, readOnly</prop>
    <prop key="get*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, readOnly</prop>
    <prop key="*"> PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, -MVARollbackException,+MVANoRollbackException </prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>


 <bean id="contextApplicationContextProvider" class="context.ApplicationContextProvider"/>  
 <bean class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator" />

 <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory">
   <ref local="baseSessionFactory" />
  </property>
 </bean>
 <!-- BUSINESS TARGET PRIMARY BUSINESS OBJECT: Hibernate implementation -->

 <bean id="localBUS" parent="txProxyTemplate" >
  <property name="target">
   <ref local="targetLocalBUS" />
  </property>
 </bean>


 <bean id="targetLocalBUS" class="bus.LocalBUS">
  <property name="localDAO">
   <ref local="local1DAO" />
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="hibernateConfiguration"
  factory-bean="&amp;baseSessionFactory"
  factory-method="getConfiguration" />



 <bean id="local1DAO" class="dao.LocalDAO" >
  <property name="sessionFactory">
   <ref local="baseSessionFactory" />
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="baseSessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource">
   <ref local="dataSource" />
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>


 <bean id="propPlaceholderConfigurer" class="advice.PropResolver" init-method="init">
  <property name="locationsMap">
   <props>
    <prop key="prod">/WEB-INF/prod.properties</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
  <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
  <property name="jdbcUrl">  
   <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@${database.url}</value>
  </property>
  <property name="properties">
   <props>
    <prop key="user">${database.user}</prop>
    <prop key="password">${database.password}</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50"/>
  <property name="initialPoolSize" value="2"/>
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
  <property name="maxStatements" value="200"/>
  <property name="maxIdleTime" value="300"/>
  <property name="acquireIncrement"  value="10"/>
  <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="90"/>
  <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="120"/>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

**And my Controller class:**

```
package view;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;

import bus.LocalBUS;

public class LocalVIEW extends MultiActionController {

 /** Logger for this class and subclasses */
 protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

 private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LocalVIEW.class);

 protected LocalBUS localBUS;

 public LocalBUS getLocalBUS() {
  return localBUS;
 }

 public void setLocalBUS(LocalBUS localBUS) {
  this.localBUS = localBUS;
 }

 @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
 public ModelAndView hnd_firstPage(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
  try {
   ConcurrentMap map = new ConcurrentHashMap();
   map.put("ad", "TK");
   logger.info("SpringappController - returning firstPage view...   TKTK");
   return new ModelAndView("firstPage", map);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return null;
  }
 }

}
```

**firstPage.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>My First MVC Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is my name : ${ad}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is the problem that you need help with?

Comment: Don't just dump a bunch of code on us without explanation. Tell us what the problem is, and what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few changes that I suggest.

1. Since you are using the Context Config Loader Listener, the contextConfigLocation parameter value for the DispatcherServlet should be empty.  As configured, it appears that you are getting 2 different application contexts for you application.
2. Include the mvc-config.xml file in the applicationConfig.xml file.

   The url mapping for the webmvc servlet should be /* (not *.*).  Note that doing this will cause your resource requests (ex. <img href="blah.gif>) to pass through spring.  I dont have an elegant solution for this, but you can use the Spring ResourceServlet and put your resources in a jar.

   You probably want to trim down your welcome file list.

   Look into using annotations for your controller.  While Annotations make your objects no longer POJOs, they do reduce the amount of spring configuration you need.

### Init param for DispatcherServlet

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation<:/param-name> 
    <param-value><:/param-value> 
</init-param>
```

### url pattern for the webmvc servlet

<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>